# How to save a conversion from degrees to radians to variable in Python

Tags: python, numpy, variables, degrees, radians

I have little bit awkward question but I couldn't figure it out by myself. I'm working on a dataset generator for my NN in Keras, and I'm feeding it with values represented as degrees (it must be degrees, not radians) and I used converter from **numpy** `np.radians(angle)`, but I could not save it as a variable. I've also tried `np.deg2rad()` but got same results. Is there any way I could some sort of "save" converted values?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you asking about saving the values temporarily? Like x = [list of radian values] which you can feed to the NN? You should give an example or a larger piece of code which helps people understand your motive.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the angle in radians like this:

```
import numpy as np

angle = 90
angle_rad = np.radians(angle)
print(angle_rad)
```

Outputs:

```
1.5707963267948966
```

If you need radian to degree conversion saved to a variable, it can be done like this:

```
import math

in_array = [0, math.pi / 2, np.pi / 3, np.pi]
print("Radian values : \n", in_array)
degree_values = np.degrees(in_array)
print("\nDegree values : \n", degree_values)
```

Which will give:

```
Radian values : 
 [0, 1.5707963267948966, 1.0471975511965976, 3.141592653589793]

Degree values : 
 [  0.  90.  60. 180.]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Yes, I've tried this, but it does not work. Is it possible that this converted value is passing as an argument into function? here:

Comment: Can you show me the error you get in your code? I will take a look.